# About Patch and Push upgrades in salesforce manage package

Tags: community

I have created a Package that is managed released. And i have installed it on other dev org. My all the classes and pages are functioning well but i am getting some error in one of my page.

I got why it is giving error. Now i have to do some modification in the one of the class in the Org where i created the managed released package and i did that. But my question is now.
1) How will i fix these changes in the installed org?
2) Do i will have to create another released or i can do it by patch or push?
3) If can do it through patch and push upgrades then how?

Please give me some information about this.

Answer (score 4):

1. How will i fix these changes in the installed org?
   You can fix these changes by installing an updated package/patch in the
   installed org. Installing an a higher version package updated your
   package code.
2. Do i will have to create another released or i can do it by patch or push?
   You can do it by both, patch or new package release. It all depends on your implementation procedures and severity of issue.  In patch you cannot add a new component, i.e. add new classes,vf pages,
   object or field etc. Also the code change in patch will not reflect
   in the main package dev org (they both are like two different org,
   except of the limitations a patch has). So as for your issue, a
   change in class can do the trick, then you can create a patch org,
   make the change in class and then release a patch.
3. If can do it through patch and push upgrades then how?
   First create a patch, make changes in your class, upload the patch and install it in the installed org.
   reference [Creating and Uploading Patches](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=patches_creating.htm&language=en_US)

Also as a side note do go through these points for [Best Practices for Push Upgrades and Patch Versions](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=push_patch_best_practices.htm&language=en_US)